# Theory or proof wanted for $\sum_\limits{k=-\infty}^\infty\exp(-2^{k+x})-\exp(-2^{k+y}) \approx y-x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to understand following approximation formula. Is there any proof or theory that gives an explanation?

$\sum_\limits{k=-\infty}^\infty\exp(-2^{k+x})-\exp(-2^{k+y}) \approx y-x$

Answer (score 1):

From 
[Analytical expressions for extreme values of $f(x):=\log(2)\left(\sum_\limits{k=-\infty}^\infty 2^{k+x}e^{-2^{k+x}}\right)-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865500/analytical-expressions-for-extreme-values-of-fx-log2-left-sum-k-infty)
we know that $f(x)\approx0$. Integrating on both sides gives $-\left(\sum_\limits{k=-\infty}^\infty\exp(-2^{k+x})-\exp(-2^{k+y})\right) - x + y\approx 0$ with some appropriate constant $y$.